# How Can I know what functions are there in an executable file?

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

I have a binary file in Linux, and I want to know what functions has it been compiled with.

My project consists on several object files, each one containing different functions. And sometimes I dont know which ones I compiled the executable with. How can I know?

I am compiling with a toolchain in different architectures (arm, mips...).

Thanks.

Comment: `nm` already has been mentioned, you can also try `objdump`, `readelf` if available. You can even `grep` to find out if the function is present, you get a message like `Binary file helloworld.o matches` when you do `grep foo helloworld.o` if `foo` is a symbol present.

Comment: Thanks, finally readelf -s and objdump -T did the trick!

Comment: [`objdump`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the **[nm](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_nm.htm)** command on unix/Linux. or
You can use **[dumpbin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429)** on Windows.

Comment: OP is not asking about Windows

Comment: @vitaut: SO is searchable with Google, though, so there's no harm in answering the question title as well as the full question with its extra limits.